# Django не может подключиться к Postgres Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

у меня такая ошибка:

```
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  |
```

мой docker-compose.yml следующий:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    hostname: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD="mypass"
      - POSTGRES_USER="user"
      - POSTGRES_DB="db"
  web:
    build: .
    hostname: mySuperApp
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: db:5432
```

Dockerfile собирается нормально, но когда начинает грузиться django с настройками в файле settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Я думал что postgres не успевает запуститься, но я попробовал следовать инструкции https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ но она не помогла

Спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `expose: - 5432` после `environment` в `db`

Answer (score 2):

У вас ошибка в параметрах соединения с БД (host будет не 'localhost', а 'db'), попробуйте вот так:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример рабочего *docker-compose.yml*. PostgreSQL + PGAdmin.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    dbpostgres:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpass
        volumes:
            - ./database/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql
        networks:
            - net

    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        ports:
            - 9080:80
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=pass
        networks:
            - net

networks: 
    net:
```

В настройки в Django будут выглядеть следующим образом:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<НАЗВАНИЕ СОЗДАННОЙ ВАМИ БД>',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pgpass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```